# The deduction theorem when there are free variables

Tags: logic

I need to use the deduction theorem in the following formulation:

Let $T$ be a first-order theory, $A \rightarrow B$ is a formula in $T$,
$x_1, ..., x_k$ are all free variables in $A$, $c_1, ..., c_k$ are new (for $T$) constant symbols,
$A(c_1, ..., c_k), B(c_1, ..., c_k)$ denote the result of replacement in $A,B$ the variables $x_i$ with $c_i$ then

$T \vdash A \rightarrow B$ iff $T[c_1, ..., c_k; A(c_1, ..., c_k)] \vdash B(c_1, ..., c_k)$

where $T[c_1, ..., c_k; A(c_1, ..., c_k)]$ denotes the theory obtained from $T$
by adding to $T$ new constant symbols $c_1, ..., c_k$ and the formula $A(c_1, ..., c_k)$ as an axiom.

What is a reference in the literature on a similarly formulated deduction theorem?

Answer (score 1):

A standard form of deduction theorem for FOL -- e.g. in Hinman, *Fundamentals of Mathematical Logic*, Theorem 3.2.15 -- has this form
$$T \cup \{\theta\} \vdash \psi \Longleftrightarrow T \vdash \theta \to \psi
\textrm{ when $\theta$ is a}\ {sentence}.$$

So, $\theta$ needs to without free variables, but $T$ and $\psi$ can feature them. So that gives you (for the one variable case)

$$T \cup \{A(c)\} \vdash B(c) \Longleftrightarrow T \vdash A(c) \to B(c)$$

But then since $c$ is new to $T$, we will have (assuming we are handling both constants and free variables in the usual sort of way)

$$T \vdash A(c) \to B(c) \Longleftrightarrow T  \vdash A(x) \to B(x)$$

Putting those together gives you what you want. I hope!